# Не работает парсер (KeyError) если можно также обьясните как парсить вк на лайки комменты (кол-во)

Tags: python, python-3.x, requests, csv, bs4

Код:

```
import requests
import csv
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs


headers={'accept':'*/*',
         'user-agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/75.0.3770.90 Safari/537.36'
}
base_url='https://vk.com/hearthstone'


def hs_parse(base_url,headers):
    stats=[]
    urls=[]
    urls.append(base_url)
    session=requests.session()
    request=session.get(base_url,headers=headers)
    while len(stats) < 60:
        if request.status_code==200:
            soup=bs(request.content,'lxml')
        for url in urls:
            request = session.get(url, headers=headers)
            soup = bs(request.content, 'lxml')
            divs = soup.find_all('div', attrs={'class': 'like_btns'})
            for a in divs:
                com=soup.find_all('a',attrs={'class':'like_btn comment _comment _reply_wrap'})
                for div in a:
                    comentators=a.find('div',attrs={'class':'like_button_count'})
                    if comentators not in stats:
                        stats.append({'comentators':comentators})
                    else:
                        pass

            for a in divs:
                lik=soup.find_all('a',attrs={'class':'like_btn like _like'})
                for div in a:
                    likes=a.find('div',attrs={'class':'like_button_count'})
                    if likes not in stats:
                        stats.append({' likes':  likes})
                    else:
                        pass
            for a in divs:
                rep = soup.find_all('a', attrs={'class': 'like_btn share _share'})
                for div in a:
                    reposts = a.find('div', attrs={'class': 'like_button_count'})
                    if reposts not in stats:
                        stats.append({' reposts': reposts})
                    else:
                        pass
            for a in divs:
                wh = soup.find_all('a', attrs={'class': 'like_views _views'})
                for div in a:
                   watching = a.find('div', attrs={'data-count': 'title'})
                   if watching not in stats:
                       stats.append({'  watching':  watching})
                   else:
                       pass
        for url in urls:
            request = session.get(url, headers=headers)
            soup = bs(request.content, 'lxml')
            content = soup.find('div', attrs={'class': 'wall_post_text'})
            if content not in stats:
                stats.append(content)
            else:
                pass
        for url in urls:
            request = session.get(url, headers=headers)
            soup = bs(request.content, 'lxml')
            author = soup.find('div', attrs={'data-post-click-type': 'post_owner_link'})
            stats.append(author)



            print(len(stats))
        else:
            print('DONE')
            print(stats)
        return stats

def files_writer(stats):
    with open('parsed_hs_pub.csv','w',encoding='utf-8'
              ) as file:
        writer=csv.writer(file)
        writer.writerow((' author','content','likes','comentators','reposts','watching'))
        for stats in stats:
            writer.writerow((stats[' author'],stats['content'],stats['likes'],stats['comentators'],stats['reposts'],stats['watching']))

stats=hs_parse(base_url,headers)
files_writer(stats)
```

Ошибка:

```
Traceback (most recent call last): File "C:/Users/User/Desktop/python 3/фриланс и примеры/Новый текстовый документ.py", line 88, in <module> files_writer(stats) File "C:/Users/User/Desktop/python 3/фриланс и примеры/Новый текстовый документ.py", line 85, in files_writer writer.writerow((stats[' author'],stats['content'],stats['likes'],stats['comentators'],stats['reposts'],stats['watching'])) KeyError: ' author'
```

Comment: Приведите, пожалуйста, трассировку ошибки.

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/User/Desktop/python 3/фриланс и примеры/Новый текстовый документ.py", line 88, in <module>
    files_writer(stats)
  File "C:/Users/User/Desktop/python 3/фриланс и примеры/Новый текстовый документ.py", line 85, in files_writer
    writer.writerow((stats[' author'],stats['content'],stats['likes'],stats['comentators'],stats['reposts'],stats['watching']))
KeyError: ' author'

Comment: Кстати, почему Вы не воспользовались ВК API? Может этот вариант подойдёт Вам?

Comment: Может быть, но можете сказать в чём ошибка именно здесь (просто даже если я буду парсить другие сайты такая ошибка может появится так что лучше знать что не так), буду признателен.

Comment: Вставьте все новую информацию из комментариев в текст вопроса.

Comment: вроде добавил описание но по мне ничего не изменилось.

Comment: И кстати как даже с vk api парсить на кол-во лайков например. (можно кодом или списком команд)

Comment: Ну вообще его и стоит использовать, ибо это быстрее, удобнее и меньше говнокода в виде парсинга html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Получение информации с помощью ВК API, как попросили в комментариях:

***Пример:***

```py
from vk_api import VkApi

vkSession = VkApi(token='Сервисный ключ')  # Не забудьте подставить сюда Ваш токен!
vk = vkSession.get_api()

wall = vk.wall.get(
    owner_id=-57989123,
    count=3
)
for i, post in enumerate(wall['items']):
    print(
        'Пост:        ', i + 1, '\n'
        'Лайков:      ', post['likes']['count'], '\n'
        'Комментариев:', post['comments']['count'], '\n'
    )
```

***stdout:***

```html
Пост:         1 
Лайков:       716 
Комментариев: 343 

Пост:         2 
Лайков:       1108 
Комментариев: 86 

Пост:         3 
Лайков:       44 
Комментариев: 70
```

Немного изменив код, можно получить практически всю информацию о посте.
Вот пример объекта `post`:

```py
{'id': 578025, 'from_id': -57989123, 'owner_id': -57989123, 'date': 1557507849, 'marked_as_ads': 0, 'post_type': 'post', 'text': 'Суперзлодей Рафаам приложил немало усилий, чтобы собрать вместе наиболее мнительных и опасных злодеев со сверхспособностями и провернуть самое амбициозное дело в своей карьере — украсть волшебный город Даларан!', 'is_pinned': 1, 'attachments': [{'type': 'video', 'video': {'id': 456239697, 'owner_id': -57989123, 'title': 'План таков... | Ролик Hearthstone: «Похищение Даларана»', 'duration': 115, 'description': 'Суперзлодей Рафаам приложил немало усилий, чтобы собрать вместе наиболее мнительных и опасных злодеев со сверхспособностями и провернуть самое амбициозное дело в своей карьере — украсть волшебный город Даларан!\n\nПосмотрите новый ролик, узнайте подробности о невероятном замысле Рафаама и приготовьтесь к новому приключению «Похищение Даларана», выход которого состоится 16 мая!\n\nУзнайте больше о новом дополнении «Возмездие теней» на сайте https://www.RiseofShadows.com', 'date': 1557496817, 'comments': 33, 'views': 200132, 'width': 1920, 'height': 1080, 'photo_130': 'https://sun9-13.userapi.com/c848524/v848524685/18be6a/nG7QFKMDr8E.jpg', 'photo_320': 'https://sun9-14.userapi.com/c848524/v848524685/18be68/rQVqYIFUdFM.jpg', 'photo_800': 'https://sun9-29.userapi.com/c848524/v848524685/18be62/fdqwsZqZ1Kc.jpg', 'photo_1280': 'https://sun9-3.userapi.com/c848524/v848524685/18be63/4NYdePXAAEM.jpg', 'first_frame_320': 'https://pp.userapi.com/c854220/v854220580/3aba2/sHN7jFkyQAg.jpg', 'first_frame_160': 'https://pp.userapi.com/c854220/v854220580/3aba7/V1Qky8KOtLg.jpg', 'first_frame_0': 'https://pp.userapi.com/c854220/v854220580/3aba5/gP6fpFx1jpg.jpg', 'first_frame_130': 'https://pp.userapi.com/c854220/v854220580/3aba8/_DSKM3GcKoo.jpg', 'first_frame_720': 'https://pp.userapi.com/c854220/v854220580/3aba3/R5Sv15iVpQ0.jpg', 'first_frame_1024': 'https://pp.userapi.com/c854220/v854220580/3aba4/qc1bUo0GEmQ.jpg', 'first_frame_1280': 'https://pp.userapi.com/c854220/v854220580/3aba1/DErc1v8_WOw.jpg', 'first_frame_800': 'https://pp.userapi.com/c854220/v854220580/3aba0/gScEEo5ycZA.jpg', 'access_key': '4aefad1cf26f4cf992', 'can_add': 1, 'track_code': 'video_9c1d70ffX0FCz7C-NmxV4DqUwTje88-CxxxQGxkFDw3MikrAQYACZ1jCt7U7VWTSCQ'}}], 'post_source': {'type': 'vk'}, 'comments': {'count': 343, 'can_post': 1, 'groups_can_post': True}, 'likes': {'count': 716, 'user_likes': 0, 'can_like': 1, 'can_publish': 1}, 'reposts': {'count': 24, 'user_reposted': 0}, 'views': {'count': 188902}}
```

Comment: Спасибо,  за пример но можете попробовать найти ошибку именно в этом коде просто мне уже самому интересно что не так а за объяснение с VK API опять же спасибо.

Comment: @rybic Я пытался :). Ваш код довольно запутан... Если найду, обязательно напишу.

Comment: Ладно буду ждать). мб что-то с табуляцией как я понял на ключи уже можно не смотреть ибо я чувствую что там куча ошибок (не то что-то указал) но тогда просто должно было быть пусто, а не ошибка.

Answer (score 2):

Вы инициализируете список `stats`:

```
stats = []
```

и добавляете в него словари:

```
stats.append({'comentators':comentators})
stats.append({' likes':  likes})
stats.append({' reposts': reposts})
stats.append({'  watching':  watching})
```

но, когда дело доходит до `author`, добавляете просто значение:

```
stats.append(author)
```

и, как следствие, на

```
writer.writerow((stats[' author'],stats['content'],stats['likes'],stats['comentators'],stats['reposts'],stats['watching']))
```

получаете ошибку `KeyError: ' author',` т.к. такого ключа там нет...

PS И с пробелами в ключах у вас чехарда: в пайтоне строки ' author' и 'author' не равны между собой.

Answer (score 1):

> можете попробовать найти ошибку именно в этом коде

Вот же подсказка: `KeyError: ' author'`

`writer.writerow()` ожидает на входе нечто типа:

```
[{' author': '...',
  'content': '...',
  'likes': '...',
  'comentators': '...',
  'reposts': '...',
  'watching': '...'}
]
```

а получает совершенно другую структуру.